# Escaping Grails render XML builder naming conflicts

Tags: grails, groovy

For example:

```
def list = {
    books = Book.findAll(...)
    render(contentType: 'text/xml') {
        books(count: books.size()) {
            for(book in books) {
                book(id: book.id) {
                    title(book.title)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using `books` and `book` as nodes cause naming conflicts.  I understand I can rename everything to prevent the issue but is there a way to *escape* the nodes to prevent the issue and keep a clean naming convention?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quote the conflicting node-generating terms:

```
 'books'(count: books.size()) {
```

or use a different local variable name.

Comment: I was under the impression that quoting only worked for reserved words.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Hubert Klein Ikkink has posted a blog entry with an alternate solution:

[Groovy Goodness: Solve Naming Conflicts with Builders](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2012/01/groovy-goodness-solve-naming-conflicts.html)

He recommends prepending `delegate` to the node names so that example would become:

```
def list = {
    books = Book.findAll(...)
    render(contentType: 'text/xml') {
        delegate.books(count: books.size()) {
            for(book in books) {
                delegate.book(id: book.id) {
                    title(book.title)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```